# R - How do I save a vector for each repeat of my loop function

Tags: r, loops, vector

I have a simple example to try and explain what I mean

```
M = matrix(sample(x,121,replace=TRUE), ncol=11, nrow=11)


x = c(1:10000)

for(m in seq(1,10,2)){
  a = rep(0,m)
  b = rep(0,m)
  c = rep(0,m)
  d = rep(0,m)
  e = rep(0,m)
  f = rep(0,m)
  g = rep(0,m)
  h = rep(0,m)
  j = rep(0,m)
  k = rep(0,m)
  l = rep(0,m)
  for(i in 1:m){
    a[i] = M[i,1] - M[i+1,1]
    b[i] = M[i,2] - M[i+1,2]
    c[i] = M[i,3] - M[i+1,3]
    d[i] = M[i,4] - M[i+1,4]
    e[i] = M[i,5] - M[i+1,5]
    f[i] = M[i,6] - M[i+1,6]
    g[i] = M[i,7] - M[i+1,7]
    h[i] = M[i,8] - M[i+1,8]
    j[i] = M[i,9] - M[i+1,9]
    k[i] = M[i,10] - M[i+1,10]
    l[i] = M[i,11] - M[i+1,11]
  } 
  r = rep(0,16)
  r[1] = length(which(b>0))
  r[3] = length(which(e<0))
  r[5] = length(which(g<0))
  r[6] = length(which(g>0))
  r[7] = length(which(h>0))
  r[9] = length(which(k<0))
  r[10] = length(which(l<0))
  r[11] = length(which(d>0)) - r[3]
  r[12] = length(which(b>0))
  r[15] = length(which(k>0))
  r[16] = length(which(l>0))
  r[8] = length(which(j>0)) - r[9]
  r[13] = length(which(c>0)) - r[5] - r[3]
  r[14] = length(which(c==0)) - r[1] - r[7] - r[8] - r[9] - r[10] - r[11] - r[12] - r[15] - r[16]
  r[4] = length(which(e>0)) - r[14]
  r[2] = length(which(c<0)) - r[4] - r[6]
  print(sum(r))
  print(r)
}
```

So if you run this, I get 5 vectors of r( when m is 1,3,5,7,9), and I print them each time giving me a vector. However, I want to save each vector for every time my loop goes. So I ideally want to name each vector like r_1, r_3,...,r_9 but I don't know how to do this.

I've tried using the `paste` function but I just keep getting errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
x = c(1:10000)

M = matrix(sample(x,121,replace=TRUE), ncol=11, nrow=11)



for(m in seq(1,10,2)){
  a = rep(0,m)
  b = rep(0,m)
  c = rep(0,m)
  d = rep(0,m)
  e = rep(0,m)
  f = rep(0,m)
  g = rep(0,m)
  h = rep(0,m)
  j = rep(0,m)
  k = rep(0,m)
  l = rep(0,m)
  for(i in 1:m){
    a[i] = M[i,1] - M[i+1,1]
    b[i] = M[i,2] - M[i+1,2]
    c[i] = M[i,3] - M[i+1,3]
    d[i] = M[i,4] - M[i+1,4]
    e[i] = M[i,5] - M[i+1,5]
    f[i] = M[i,6] - M[i+1,6]
    g[i] = M[i,7] - M[i+1,7]
    h[i] = M[i,8] - M[i+1,8]
    j[i] = M[i,9] - M[i+1,9]
    k[i] = M[i,10] - M[i+1,10]
    l[i] = M[i,11] - M[i+1,11]
  }
  r = rep(0,16)
  r[1] = length(which(b>0))
  r[3] = length(which(e<0))
  r[5] = length(which(g<0))
  r[6] = length(which(g>0))
  r[7] = length(which(h>0))
  r[9] = length(which(k<0))
  r[10] = length(which(l<0))
  r[11] = length(which(d>0)) - r[3]
  r[12] = length(which(b>0))
  r[15] = length(which(k>0))
  r[16] = length(which(l>0))
  r[8] = length(which(j>0)) - r[9]
  r[13] = length(which(c>0)) - r[5] - r[3]
  r[14] = length(which(c==0)) - r[1] - r[7] - r[8] - r[9] - r[10] - r[11] - r[12] - r[15] - r[16]
  r[4] = length(which(e>0)) - r[14]
  r[2] = length(which(c<0)) - r[4] - r[6]
  varName = paste("r_",m,sep = "")
  # print(varName)
  assign(varName,r,envir = .GlobalEnv )
}
```

Then you can print one of the saved r lists:

```
print(r_1)
 [1]  0 -5  0  4  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1 -3  0  1
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with this, I don't know how to get this into my loop function.

Comment: You can just append the values to your vector.

v = append(v, value) # where "v" is a generic vector and value is your value or list of values.